# Sanitize input before passing it as a variable to stored procedure from java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have a java code that calls a stored procedure and return a search result to the web browser, the problem i am facing is that the procedure accepts parameter from the browser, now even if I use a PreparedStatement in java the user input is only sanitized for the call of the procedure but once the passed value enters the stored procedure, it is again vulnerable to SQL Injection,

here is a code Snippets

Java code

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement("call myProcedure(?,?)");  
.
.
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

my mysql Procedure:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(IN userinput1 VARCHAR(255), IN unserinput2 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    myTable
where 
    col1 = userinput1
    and col2 = userinput2
ORDER BY id;  


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I can solve this issue if I redesign my procedure as such :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(IN userinput1 VARCHAR(255), IN unserinput2 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @query = concat(“SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = ? and col2 = ?“);
SET @a = userinput1;
SET @b = unserinput2; 
PREPARE stmt from @query;
EXECUTE stmt using @a, @b;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But my issue is, the application I am working on has already has lot of procedures and function designed as such and I don't want to have to go in and redesign all of the procedure one by one.

Is there any particular way where i could pre-sanitize the input before passing it to the procedure itself.

Also filtering out SQL keywords are not an option as there are several codes that allows free text, it's an old implementation of multi-purpose stored procedure that works perfectly beside the injectable scenario.

Comment: You should *never* accept any parameter from the web without sanitizing it. There are too many ways for applications to be broken by accidental or malicious input.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injection,
Usually there are SQL keywords in statements, such as [ "master", "truncate", "insert", "select", "delete", "update", "declare", "alter", "drop"],You need to filter your parameters，If the keyword is included, give an error prompt to the browser